# C# what's the fastest to copy all the data (from Access Database) into list and dictionary

Tags: c#, ms-access, optimization, query-optimization

**Discription of the project**

I am creating two windows form application in which one form can insert, search and export (into a word doc) the data and other one will Update and delete the data. those data comes from a Access database that has  10 tables:

- STAKEHOLDERS_ST
- STAKEHOLDERS_STAFF_SST
- STAKEHOLDERS_RELATED_DOCUMENT_STRD
- RECENT_INTERACTIONS_RI
- RECENT_INTERACTIONS_PARTICIPANTS_RIP
- RECENT_INTERACTION_MATERIALS_PREPARED_RIMP
- ODI_STAFF_OS (did not use yet)
- MEETINGS_MET
- MEETINGS_NOTES_MN
- BRIDGE_ST_MET

These tables are related like this:
[image]

In order to access the data from DB, I have decided to create dictionaries and lists and copy all the data into those collections. With that, the program will easily display the data in the GUI with a reasonable speed. Also, whenever the users wants to display a certain information of a Stakeholder, the program will use lamba expression and Linq to display the data. At first, my first attempt was directly get the info's from DB by using SQL queries, but I notice that the process was very slow.

**My problem**

In general, all the main function (display data in GUI and insert,update,delete data in DB) in the App works fine. However, **my only concern is about the amount of time for loading data into the collections and displaying forms**. More specifically, whenever the user lunch a form, their form_load event in which the program will populate 9 collection: 3 dictionaries and 6 lists. But, I notice that it will take some time (~6 sec for 10 records in each table) for loading these data and displaying GUI.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
//Collection data
Dictionary<int, ST_Stakeholder> List_ST;
List<SST_StakeholderStaff> List_SST;
List<STRD_Stakeholder_Related_Document> List_STRD;
Dictionary<int, RI_Recent_Interaction> List_RI;
List<RIP_Recent_Interaction_Participants> List_RIP;
List<RIMP_Recent_Interaction_Materials_Prepared> List_RIMP;
Dictionary<int, MET_Meeting> List_MET;
List<MN_Meeting_notes> List_MN;
List<Tuple<int, int>> List_BR;


private void EditSTInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Fill the Collection
        List_ST = new Dictionary<int, ST_Stakeholder>(DatabaseConnection.DicStakeholderInformation());
        List_SST = new List<SST_StakeholderStaff>(DatabaseConnection.ListStakeholderStaff());
        List_STRD = new List<STRD_Stakeholder_Related_Document>(DatabaseConnection.ListStakeholderDocument());
        List_RI = new Dictionary<int, RI_Recent_Interaction>(DatabaseConnection.DicRecentInteraction());
        List_RIP = new List<RIP_Recent_Interaction_Participants>(DatabaseConnection.ListRecentInteractionParticipants());
        List_RIMP = new List<RIMP_Recent_Interaction_Materials_Prepared>(DatabaseConnection.ListRecentInteractionMaterials());
        List_MET = new Dictionary<int, MET_Meeting>(DatabaseConnection.DicMeeting());
        List_MN = new List<MN_Meeting_notes>(DatabaseConnection.ListMeetingNotes());
        List_BR = new List<Tuple<int, int>>(DatabaseConnection.DicBrige());

        //Display the Stakeholder Name in the List Bos
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ST_Stakeholder> item in List_ST)
        {
            lbListStakeholder.Items.Add(item.Value.ST_Name);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        DatabaseConnection.CloseDB();
    }
}
```

PS: the DataBaseConnection is static class in which must of the functions will execute SQL commands. here a example for DatabaseConnection.DicStakeholderInformation()

```
//Display the data
//Function that return a dictionnary of Stakeholder information
public static Dictionary<int, ST_Stakeholder> DicStakeholderInformation()
{
    Dictionary<int, ST_Stakeholder> result = new Dictionary<int, ST_Stakeholder>();
    _CncxBD.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(stListStakeholderinfo, _CncxBD);
    OleDbDataReader row = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (row.Read())
    {
        result.Add((int)row["ST_ID"], new ST_Stakeholder((string)row["ST_Name"], (string)row["ST_Address"], (string)row["ST_City"], (string)row["ST_Province"], (string)row["ST_Postal_Code"], (string)row["ST_Vision"], (string)row["ST_Objectives"], (string)row["ST_Major_Successes"], (string)row["ST_Gorvernance"], (string)row["ST_Funding_Structure"], (string)row["ST_Type_of_work"], (string)row["ST_Scope"], row["ST_Additional_Information"].ToString()));
    }

    _CncxBD.Close();

    return result;

}
```

With that I was just wondering if someone can help me to optimizing the speed for  all this work! my first idea was probably to create multiple Thread in order to fill the collections. but I think that you can't use thread with collection because it's not safe. anyway I just need some ideas for speeding up the process.

Comment: Opening and closing DB connections is time consuming.  You should open 1 connection when you start the app, reuse this, and only close when you are finished.   Next I suggest that you time how long each collection takes to load and focus on the slowest, where the best gains can be made.  And then use parallelism these slowest parts in background threads.

Comment: I am pretty new with Thread, can you explain me on how to use parallelism and send me some example. As for the Opening and closing DB connections I will create a void for avoiding the repetition. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Just to be clear: When a form is opened are you populating all of those data structures with the entire contents of each table, or are you only loading the items that are relevant to (the current state of) the particular form in question?

Comment: You are creating a new Dictionary in your static method then passing it immediately into another dictionary just to make a copy.  Instead, use the object returned by the static functions directly.  That's a waste to always make copies of collection objects.

Comment: just  some of the forms (precise: Forms are ExportData, Search and EditData), I will create the collections and population them (all the data on each table) when the form is loading (Load_event). Idk if I answer your question  correctly @GordThompson.

Comment: @CPerkins - It is quite common for an application to keep a single persistent connection to a file-based database like Access. Having such a connection open for long periods of inactivity is not generally regarded as being problematic, and I don't recall ever seeing credible evidence that doing so "can increase chances of database corruption" unless the open connection also has a pending transaction that never gets committed or rolled back.

Comment: One more thing with ADO.NET, wich object is faster for reading the data in DB: DBDataReader or (OleDbDataAdapter with DataTable) or something else ?

Comment: @JacobC. - I was just trying to ascertain whether you were essentially loading the entire database into memory. It might be better to use "lazy loading" to pull the relevant rows from the database as you need them, rather than make the user wait while you load the whole thing up-front.

Comment: @GordThompson what do you mean about lazy loading

Comment: @JacobC. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

Comment: @Gord I removed my comment. Searches elsewhere confirm it is a common practice to maintain a persistent DB connection, but at the least I think such a statement requires a good reference with an explanation of good practices.  Just as you say, it is not a problem if there are no pending transactions (or open recordsets), but care should be taken to ensure DB updates and transactions are wrapped with proper error handling, etc.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith just by creating a void that will open and close the DB connection, the form load is more faster (~ 1-3 sec). but I have to test my DB has more than 1000 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can create different task and run it in different threads.

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { your code here});
```

later on if your next step depends on this data to be loaded you can add all task that you have created to a list.

```
List<Task> lst = new List<Task>();
```

and later make your application wait for all those task to finish to continue.

```
  Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Imagine that you have created 4 different Task, you have group your procedures by the time that takes, and you have create 4 task, every task will run in a different thread, and they will run in parallel.

i hope this help you, probably there is a better way to do it. I do it sometimes to speed up heavy processing.

if your next code doesn't depend on this dictionary being filled to continue just dont wait for the task and continue, they will keep working in the background.

Thank you

Comment: for the `Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { your code here});` what do i put in side of () ? Also, Can I fill a dictionnary or a list like this:  `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { List_ST = new Dictionary<int, ST_Stakeholder>(DatabaseConnection.DicStakeholderInformation()) });`

Comment: Hi @JacobC. nothing is inside the () you left empty is a delegate, a generic delegate. you leave it empty.

Comment: yes @JacobC. you can put the code to fill the Dictionary inside the Task so it will run in a different Thread. I would recommend to put in every task more than one, test it to see how performance is improve.
Thanks

Comment: Hi @SergioCareraGari So based on what you have publish, I code the same thing, but my list are still emplty and IDK why. Here will publish my code in the answer section

Comment: Hi @JacobC. trace your code and check if the list are filled. thats weird because the task.factory.startnew will start the task as soon as you declare it. so it will run instantly.
trace your code step by step check the methods that returns the data from DB to doublecheck that they are returning data.

Comment: @SergioCareraGari when I debug the app I notice that some of the collections does not contain all the item in the DB (so they do not get all the data) or other are null

Comment: The issue could be that Task.Factory.StarNew is not task aware.

You can use Task.Run instead or add unwrap() to the task.factory.startnew.

       Task.Run(() => { List_ST = new Dictionary<int, ST_Stakeholder>(); }),

or like this 
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { List_ST = new Dictionary<int, ST_Stakeholder>(); }).Unwrap(),

Comment: Yes i know what is happening is at the end just running the last one complete. Make that modification and tell me if it works.

Comment: It's still the same: there is only 4 collections that their not fill: List_ST, List_RI, List_RIP and List_RIMP

Comment: it's work! I just did a error (if forgot to call DataBase.DicStakeholderInformation in order to fill the the List_ST. as for for the order, the table are empty. Thank you so much ! @Sergio

Comment: One more thing is it possible to rerun one or + task in the list ?

Comment: good to know @JacobC. Yes you can run it at any time independently. for example you have all task in a list, suppose you want to rerun the task that is at index 4 yous get the task at index 4 and call the run method.

Comment: their no run method when you get a certain task by using the index. I could not start the task. do you have any example for rerunning a task ?

Comment: I will test it on my side, but as my understanding you can make something like this.  list[3].Run(); Because list is a list of task and the one in the position 3 just call the run method.